# Not found js files in project (NextJs and ReactJs)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I ran into a problem importing js files (these are libraries). I am using NextJS 14.1.3 and ReactJS 18.2.0.

Here is the path to these files
[Here is the path to these files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahwjZ.png)

Project structure
[Project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tuOo1.png)

This is the way I imported the files

```
import Script from 'next/script';

render() {
        const {Component, pageProps}: any = this.props;

        // During SSR, this will create new store instances so having `initialData` is crucial.
        // During the client-side hydration, same applies.
        // From then on, calls to `getStores()` return existing instances.
        const stores = getStores();

        return (
            <StoreProvider value={stores}>
                <Script
                    src='/public/js/LunaPass.1.6.8.js'
                    strategy="beforeInteractive"
                />
                <Script
                    src='/public/js/LPMessageRenderer.1.6.8.js'
                    strategy="beforeInteractive"
                />
                <Component {...pageProps} />
            </StoreProvider>
        );
    }
```

Error itself
[Error in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvq6d.png)

Has anyone encountered such a problem?

My expectation of my actions is to import js files and then use them in other pages.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to put the /public part you just have to use "/js/(script name)".

Comment: i tried this way, but it didn't help

Comment: What's the error? In your browser try to open this link `http://localhost:3000/js/LunaPass.1.6.8.js` what's the output?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelbaset there is not any output

Comment: You should be able to view files in public dir from the browser. Are you sure u entered the name of files and extensions right?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by adding module.exports = {} in js file